# form sent by action instead of javascript although return false

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms

My question goes a little bit deeper than written in the headline.
Let me explain the situation.
I´m building a form for buying a product which is divided in steps through the plugin [FormToWizard](http://www.jankoatwarpspeed.com/turn-any-webform-into-a-powerful-wizard-with-jquery-formtowizard-plugin/) using JQuery. Furthermore I´m using [Validate](http://jquery.dop-trois.org/walidate/) to validate it easily and with customizable effects and Reveal.js by ZURB (sorry can´t post more links because of my missing reputation) for nice modals to handle occurring errors.

My Proceeding:

- The validate function is started when website finished loading and
  when the form is submitted it scans the whole form again.
- So I told validate to set the variable error true if there´s an error
  and to set it false if there´s no error.
- Afterwards it should call the function send() which deals with the
  modals and the sending of the form.
- It also has got a return false inside to prevent the html to send it
  the natural way.

My Problem:

1. As soon as the code of the function send becomes too big it isn´t
   proceeded properly anymore and suddenly interrupted by the .php file
   called it the action tag of the form.
2. If I reduce the numbers of lines in the function send() it works the
   way it should. but these additional lines are very important.

So what can I do to avoid this?

I´ve already tried to wrap both functions in a `$("#auftragsform").submit()` function but this didn´t work either. I´ve tried a whole bunch of things and thought of everything I know and I can do, but don´t find a solution.

Here´s my code:

```
$(window).load(function(){    
        $('#auftragsformular').walidate({
            submitSelector: 'input[type="submit"]',
            doIfAllIsValid: function() {
                error = false;
                send();
            },
            doIfSomethingIsInvalid: function() {
                error = true;
                send();
            }
        }); // Initalize the form
        $('#name').walidate('validate'); // Make this element required
        $('#email').walidate('validate', {
            eventHandler: 'blur keyup',
            expression: /^([a-zA-Z0-9_\.\-])+\@(([a-zA-Z0-9\-])+\.)+([a-zA-Z]{2,10})+$/,
            invalid: function() {                  
                $(this).tipTip({ delay: 100, defaultPosition: "top", activation: "focus" });
            },
        });
        $('#plz').walidate('validate');
        $('#ort').walidate('validate');
        $('#strasse').walidate('validate');
        $('#hausnr').walidate('validate');
        $('#hoehe').walidate('validate');
        $('#breite').walidate('validate');
        $('input[type=radio][name=varianten]').walidate('validate');
        $('#agb').walidate('validate');
});

function send(){
    if (error == false) {
        if (is_not_bot()) {
            var name = $("#name").val();
            var email = $("#email").val();
            var adresse = $("#uebersicht_d").text();
            var auftrag = $("#uebersicht_a").text();

            $.post('assets/scripts/php/auftragform.php', "name=" + name + "&email=" + email + "&adresse=" + adresse + "&auftrag=" + auftrag, function(msg) {
                    $("#form").slideUp(1000);
                    $("#answer").delay(1000).fadeIn(1500);
                    console.log(msg);   
            });
        }
        return false;
    }

    if (error == true) {
        $('#errorModal').reveal();
        if ($("#versteckt_variante:checked").val() == "nix") {
            $("#alert_varianten").show();
            $("#felderhardcopy").hide();
        }
        if (!$("#agb").attr("checked")) {
            $("label[for=agb]").css("color", "red");
        }
        $("#step0").show();
        $("#step1").hide();
        $("#step2").hide();
        $("#senden").hide();
        selectStep(1);
        return false;
    }
}
```

HTML:

```
<form title="Auftrag" id="auftragsformular" action="assets/scripts/php/auftragform.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">     
        <div id="formcontainer">
            <fieldset title="Kontaktdaten" id="Kontakt"> 
            <legend> Ihre Daten </legend>

                <div class="left">
                    <label for="firma"> Firma</label>
                    <p> <input type="text" name="firma" id="firma" placeholder="Ihre Firma" > </p>

                    <label for="name"> Name</label>
                    <p> <input type="text" name="name" id="name" placeholder="Ihr kompletter Name (erforderlich)"> </p>

                    <label for="email"> Email-Adresse</label> 
                    <p> <input type="text" name="email" id="email" placeholder="Ihre Email (erforderlich)">
                     <a href="#" class="tip-trigger help"><span style="top: -150px;">Eine korrekte, existierende Email-Adresse wie z.B. max.mustermann@online.de ist erforderlich! Kommas, Umlaute, Klammern und Sonderzeichen sind verboten!</span>?</a>
                    </p>

                    <label for="tel"> Telefon</label> 
                    <p> <input type="tel" name="tel" id="tel" placeholder="Ihre Telefonnummer">
                         <a href="#" class="tip-trigger"><span style="top: -110px;">Durch Ihre Telefonnummer können wir Sie schneller erreichen</span>?</a>
                    </p>
                </div>

                <div class="left">
                    <label for="plz"> Postleitzahl</label> 
                    <p> <input type="number" name="plz" id="plz" placeholder="Ihre Postleitzahl (erforderlich)"></p>

                    <label for="ort">Ort</label> 
                    <p> <input type="text" name="ort" id="ort" placeholder="Ihr Wohnort (erforderlich)"></p>

                    <label for="strasse"> Straße</label> 
                    <p> <input type="text" name="strasse" id="strasse" placeholder="Ihre Straße (erforderlich)"></p>

                    <label for="hausnr"> HausNr.</label> 
                    <p> <input type="number" name="hausnr" id="hausnr" placeholder="Ihre Hausnummer (erforderlich)"></p>
                </div>

                <div class="clear"></div>
            </fieldset>




            <fieldset title="Auftrag" id="auftrag">
            <legend> Der Auftrag </legend>

                <label for="hoehe"> Maße des Sicherungskasten(cm)</label>
                <p> <input type="number" name="hoehe" id="hoehe" placeholder="Höhe (erforderlich)"> </p>
                <p style=""> <input type="number" name="breite" id="breite" placeholder="Breite (erforderlich)"></p>


                <div style="position: relative">
                    <label> Wählen Sie die Art des Auftrags </label><p></p>
                    <div class="left radio">
                        <label for="vorlage"> <img src="assets/images/cupcake.jpg" height="200px"/><br/> Motiv aus den Vorlagen auswählen</label> <br/>
                        <input type="radio" class="radio" name="varianten" id="vorlage" value="ausgewählte Vorlage" style="display:none;">
                    </div>
                    <div class="left radio">
                        <label for="digital"> <img src="assets/images/placeholder.png" height="200px"/><br/> Ein Bild hochladen</label> <br/>
                        <input type="radio" class="radio" name="varianten" id="digital" value="ein digitales Bild hochladen" style="display:none;">
                    </div>
                    <div class="left radio">
                        <label for="hardcopy"> <img src="assets/images/hardcopy.jpg" height="200px"/><br/> Ein gedrucktes Bild einsenden </label> <br/>
                        <input type="radio" class="radio" name="varianten" id="hardcopy" value="ein Bild einsenden" style="display:none;">
                    </div>
                    <input type="radio" class="radio" name="varianten" id="versteckt_variante" value="nix" style="display:none;">

                    <div class="clear"></div>
                    <div id="alert_varianten" class="alert"> Bitte wählen Sie eine Variante aus!</div>
                </div>
```

left some parts out, because form is too huge. If they seem to be important which I don´t think, because they are just regardless fields, I will post them.

```
        <p> <input type="checkbox" id="agb" name="agb" value="agb" style="width: auto;"> <label for="agb">Um einen Auftrag abzuschicken müssen Sie die <a href="../agb">AGB</a> akzeptieren</label></p>

    </fieldset>

    <p class="nosee">
      <label for="your_email">This isn´t requested, just a robot detection field:</label>
      <input id="your_email" name="your_email" size="60" value="" />
    </p>

    <input type="submit" value="Abschicken" id="senden" class="buttonwichtig">

</div>
</form>
```

Comment: find which function is called on submit, it will be receiving the `event` object as argument, in that function do `event.preventDefault()` .

Answer (score 0):

Instead of trying to use a global variable, how about this:

```
$(window).load(function(){    
    $('#auftragsformular').walidate({
        submitSelector: 'input[type="submit"]',
        doIfAllIsValid: function() {
            return send(false);
        },
        doIfSomethingIsInvalid: function() {
            return send(true);
        }
    });
    // ...
    // Code removed for brevity
});

function send(error) {
    if (!error) {
        if (is_not_bot()) {
            var name = $("#name").val();
            var email = $("#email").val();
            var adresse = $("#uebersicht_d").text();
            var auftrag = $("#uebersicht_a").text();

            $.post('assets/scripts/php/auftragform.php', "name=" + name + "&email=" + email + "&adresse=" + adresse + "&auftrag=" + auftrag, function(msg) {
                $("#form").slideUp(1000);
                $("#answer").delay(1000).fadeIn(1500);
                console.log(msg);   
            });
        }
    } else {
        $('#errorModal').reveal();
        if ($("#versteckt_variante:checked").val() == "nix") {
            $("#alert_varianten").show();
            $("#felderhardcopy").hide();
        }
        if (!$("#agb").attr("checked")) {
            $("label[for=agb]").css("color", "red");
        }
        $("#step0").show();
        $("#step1, #step2, #senden").hide();
        selectStep(1);
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: I changed this, but it didn´t help. I think the problem is that the php script called in the action tag of the form starts working although it shouldn´t.

Answer (score 0):

PROBLEM SOLVED
 I´ve just used a "fake" button and connected all the functions to it, so only the action of the form remains for the real submit button. I´ve used JQuery to hide/show the buttons, so that anybody who has turned off javascript sees the real submit button which delivers the form the php script